# How to use flash.sampler.getSamples to test garbage collection

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to unit test memory management. So far I have a semi-workable solution using `flash.sampler.getSamples` to get the difference between the number of NewObjectSamples and DeleteObjectSamples which have the same id value.

The test looks something like this:

```
startSampling();
new Foo();
new Foo();
new Foo();
forceGC();
pauseSampling();
countAllocations(Foo); // returns 1, should return 0
```

The countAllocations() method gets the difference between the number of NewObjectSamples and DeleteObjectSamples for a specific class:

```
    public static function countAllocations(type:Class):int
    {
        var count:int = 0;
        var allocations:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        for each (var sample:Sample in getSamples()) {
            if (sample is NewObjectSample) {
                var newObjectSample:NewObjectSample = sample as NewObjectSample;
                if ((newObjectSample.type == type) && (newObjectSample.object != null)) {
                    allocations[newObjectSample.id] = true;
                    count ++;
                }
            } 
            else if (sample is DeleteObjectSample) {
                var deleteObjectSample:DeleteObjectSample = sample as DeleteObjectSample;
                if (allocations[deleteObjectSample.id]) 
                    count --;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The forceGC() method uses the LocalConnection hack to force garbage collection:

```
public static function forceGC():void {
        try {
            new LocalConnection().connect("bdebdd96-7bf8-407b-bec9-8336b2b0c329");
            new LocalConnection().connect("bdebdd96-7bf8-407b-bec9-8336b2b0c329");
        }
        catch (error:Error) {
        }
}
```

Stepping through the code shows that:

```
NewObjectSample Foo id=1 (count = 1)
NewObjectSample Foo id=2 (count = 2)
NewObjectSample Foo id=3 (count = 3)
// NewObjectSamples related to the LocalConnection hack
DeleteObjectSample id=2 (count = 2)
DeleteObjectSample id=1 (count = 1)
// Where's wally #3??
```

Since there are no references to Foo I'm assuming that all instances are being garbage collected, and my code is simply wrong due to my lack of understanding how sampling works. I am trying this instead of using weakly keyed dictionary because it seems it should be less of a hack, but now I'm starting to wonder if it's worth the trouble.

Comment: This isn't worth an answer, but `new Dictionary(true)` is reliable in my experience.  Plus, you can run your tests in the release player.

Comment: @sean-fujiwara True, and I currently do use a dictionary currently. The advantage I'm hoping to gain from this is simplicity by not having to keep explicit references for each object in the dictionary.

Comment: You can use `System.gc()` instead of the gc hack if you're using the debug player. Also, there isn't much of a way to test garbage collection since any test you will make will always be of the kind "create X, delete X" which will work every time unless you add a lot of weird situations in it.  In my experience, adding better coding standards is the best way to go for GC, then do profiling manually.

Comment: @j-a-x Thanks for the input. The intention is to use this for test driven development - as a way to drive development of disposable classes. It's also nice to be able to test memory leaks in unit tests rather than using the runtime profiler. The reason I'm not using `System.gc()` is that it only runs the collector on the next `EnterFrame` whereas the hack runs the GC immediately, meaning the tests don't have to be asynchronous meaning they are simpler.

Comment: You want to use a GC hack for tests? Deal with the complex (async) testing, even if it may be more difficult. Don't use something inherently unreliable for testing.

Comment: @sam-dehaan Thank you for the advice, however the point of the question is how to use getSamples() and avoid using a Dictionary. I don't have anything against Dictionaries (they are people too), but it seems more correct to use the sampler to measure memory since that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the gc over consecutive frames. I have the same problem. I spent about 2 days trying to track down a memory leak that I thought I had (I use the weak key Dictionary method to check it). Turns out it just didn't get collected the first time

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm actually less interested in the exact GC method used, and more interested in how to measure memory usage using getSamples() as stated in the title of the question. Even using System.GC(), the question still remains as how to inspect memory allocations and de-allocations using the sampler.

Comment: my point being that the only thing i'd change about your sampling (aside from tracing out all `DeleteObjectSample`s) is to run it over multiple frames, with the gc in between. Your problem at the minute is that you're missing the 3rd `Foo`, which could be just that it hasn't been collected yet, rather than there being a problem with your code.

Comment: You could also check out the code from the FlashPreloadProfiler: http://code.google.com/p/flashpreloadprofiler/ which does some of this stuff if I remember correctly. Just check up the issues to get it working as there's a few small bugs that stop it working from the off.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying - that makes sense. I won't be able to try it out before the bounty expires but if it turns out to be the correct solution I'll allocate the bounty to you some other way.

Comment: @lukevanin. Sorry to interrupt your question. I am trying to contact you. it seems you know how to download content via air without using the save box. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039772/actionscript-downloading-a-file-using-filereference I really need help with this. But I don't know how to contact you outside of this. Thanks ed.vizenor@gmail.com