# Actionscript downloading a File using FileReference

Tags: actionscript

I'm having trouble working on `FileReference` `download(URL) function`. I needed to automatically download the files in a particular space on my harddisk but the SAVE AS dialog always displays. can I make it automatically `download` in a certain place on my disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume "automatically download" means "save" here. Nope, If you use `FileReference` (or `File` in AIR), there's no way to automatically save without showing the Save As dialog box.

If you don't need to access the file outside of the app, then take a look at the `SharedObject` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html. By default you can create `SharedObject`s of up to 100KB without needing the client's permission (see the description of `getLocal()`), which should be fine for more simple text or xml info - you can compress it using `ByteArray` if you want to save space. Any more than that and a small dialog will open asking permission. Once you've given permission however, it won't ask again.

Comment: thanks! yeah... i only need those file inside my app and i dont need to access it outside. can I make it store an array of example image file? example is i want to store 10 images with 200KB each can I do that? thanks again for your response

Comment: you can store the bitmap data of the images in a vector, then save it to the `SharedObject`, though the first time you do it, it'll show the dialog asking for 2mb save space. If the images don't change, consider directly embedding them instead: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html (you can pretty much ignore the [Bindable] tag)

Comment: The statment "Nope, If you use FileReference (or File in AIR), there's no way to automatically save without showing the Save As dialog box." isn't entirely correct. Using AIR it is possible to download the file using a URLLoader() then write it using File.save(), all without showing a "save" dialog.